# How to select two conditions in one column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have three tables:

**Table products**

```
ID | Name
1 | Pizza A
2 | Pizza B
3 | Pizza C
```

**Table components**

```
ID | NAME
1 | cheese
2 | salami
3 | potato
4 | onion
5 | ananas
```

**Table product_components**

```
ID | product_id | component_id
1 | 1 | 1
2 | 1 | 5
3 | 2 | 1
4 | 3 | 5
5 | 3 | 3
```

I want to get only pizza with cheese AND ananas (Pizza A). How Can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select p.name
from product p
join product_components c1 on c1.id_pizza = p.id
join product_components c2 on c2.id_pizza = p.id
where c1.name = 'cheese'
  and c2.name = 'salami'
```

If you want to exclude pizzas which have more than just cheese and salami, you can extend the query with an "excluding LEFT JOIN":

```
select p.name
from product p
join product_components c1 on c1.id_pizza = p.id
join product_components c2 on c2.id_pizza = p.id
left join product_components other
  on  other.id_pizza = p.id
  and other.name not in (c1.name, c2.name)
where c1.name = 'cheese'
  and c2.name = 'salami'
  and other.name is null
```

#### Update

For the changed schema the queries would be something like

```
select p.name
from products p
join product_components pc1 on pc1.product_id = p.id
join components         c1  on c1.id = pc1.component_id
join product_components pc2 on pc2.product_id = p.id
join components         c2  on c2.id = pc2.component_id
where c1.name = 'cheese'
  and c2.name = 'salami'
```

```
select p.name
from products p
join product_components pc1 on pc1.product_id = p.id
join components         c1  on c1.id = pc1.component_id
join product_components pc2 on pc2.product_id = p.id
join components         c2  on c2.id = pc2.component_id
left join product_components pco
  on  pco.product_id = p.id
  and pco.component_id not in (pc1.component_id, pc2.component_id)
where c1.name = 'cheese'
  and c2.name = 'salami'
  and pco.component_id is null
```

Comment: Ok it works for two columns. Now I must add one more (please show post)

Comment: @Jack Next time please don't change your questions if it would make given answers invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Group By` and `Having` clause

```
select p.Name 
from product_components pc 
inner join product p on pc.ID_PIZZA = p.id
where name in ('cheese' ,'salami')
Group by p.Name
having count(distinct pc.Name)= 2
```

The above query will return the Pizza which has both `'cheese'` and `'salami'`. But the same pizza can have some other component as well.

or if you want the pizza which only has `'cheese'` and `'salami'` then you need to tweak the `Having` clause a little

```
select p.Name 
from product_components pc 
inner join product p on pc.ID_PIZZA = p.id
Group by p.Name
having sum(case when name in ('cheese' ,'salami') then 1 else 0 end) = count(*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.Name FROM product P
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID_PIZZA, GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY name) AS INGR
            FROM product_components
            GROUP BY ID_PIZZA
           ) t
ON T.ID_PIZZA = P.ID
AND T.INGR = 'cheese,salami'
```

Comment: What if the `salami` is present before `cheese`. I think it is safe to add `T.INGR in ( 'cheese,salami', 'salami,cheese')`. Also if the data is duplicated like two salami and one cheese are present for a pizza it will fail.

Comment: You can use `ORDER BY name` for `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - Inside a sub-query, will `Order by` work without `Limit` in `Mysql` ? am a noob in Mysql ;)

Comment: Not in the subquery: `GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY name)`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - Ok.. so we have an option to mention it inside the function itself. Good to know. If you can add `Distinct` as well, then duplicates can also be handled